# How to update models in visual studio code from database in Entity Core in asp.net core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

By VS 2017, I created an project (database ), everything it's working well。
now I made changes in the CLI commands add new tables(Test)  , the question is how to update models to match the database in SQL?

But I don't know how to update the model when the database has been edit. add new table(modelsTest) I using CLI commands

i have reference For detailed information about dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold command https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold

test CLI commands :

1. dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\v11.0;Database=xxx;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t modelsTest

2.dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=xxx;Database=xxx;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxxx;Integrated Security=false;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t modelsTest -f

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1lpX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3r0v.png)

this is a screenshot for my project:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfi7v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that there are many [differences between Entity Framework 6 and Entity Framework Core (EF Core)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/#creating-a-model), and currently no support for edmx in EF Core.

| **Feature** | **EF6.4** | **EF Core** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Model format: EDMX (XML) | Yes | No support planned |

And the command `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` that you referenced does work with EF Core.